# How to setup index schema for supporting an retail application

Tags: elasticsearch

How to configure index schema for supporting an retail application selling various shoes, mobiles

1. Shoes have a bunch of attributes which is categorized under shoes
2. Mobiles have a different bunch of attributes which is categorized under mobiles

How should we setup an index for users to allow searching across shoes or mobiles

Comment: i believe Elastic's philosophy is to denormalise and store dependent props as nested json. Have you explored something along these lines?

Comment: not really, I am not sure what would be the ideal design for supporting a hierarchical data model for representing items sold under different categories. would you suggest a structure on how you would propose that would be

Comment: Is it necessary to have one index? You could have two indices - one for mobiles and another for shoes. Some of the fields will be common to both indices and the rest would be different. You could then write a query to search both the indices. Queries that are on specific fields will search only one index, but queries on common fields would search both.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid the above approach as based on the number of categories, I would have to construct and maintain many indexes